# Does Akka have a react as well like Scala? or is it handled by dispatchers?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

According to my understanding, it does not, there are 2 ways to create an actor which is by either extending the Actor class and implementing receive or by creating an anonymous Actor using one of the actor methods. So far so good.

Akka has a concept of dispatchers (http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/dispatchers.html), so does that mean that once I create an actor and implement the receive, by default I get the event dispatcher which is similar to the react in Scala? Of course, if i need to tie my actor to the thread of the OS then I would be using the thread based dispatcher, is this similar to receive in Scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Akka has a concept of dispatchers (http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/dispatchers.html), so does that mean that once I create an actor and implement the receive, by default I get the event dispatcher which is similar to the react in Scala?

Yes.

> Of course, if i need to tie my actor to the thread of the OS then I would be using the thread based dispatcher, is this similar to receive in Scala?

Yes.